# Want to limit amount of posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am making a site where users can only submit a post once, and then the "new post" button goes away forever.

I would also like to put a limit on the overall amount of posts. So, only the first 100 or so people can actually post.

I used rails generate scaffold to build the posting system.

I don't know where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a constant if all user will have the same limit, or add a field in your user record if you plan for each user to have different limits.

Then you create a validator which check the number of existing posts and forbid creation of new posts if the limit is reached

More info in rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is using a policy object. Here's how I would approach this using [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit).

**Updated:**

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.limit_exceeded?(max = 100)
    count >= max
  end
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post
end
```

**app/policies/post_policy.rb**

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def create?
    !user_has_post? && space_to_post?
  end

  private

  def user_has_post?
    user.post.present?
  end

  def space_to_post?
    !Post.limit_exceeded?
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    authorize(:post)
    @post = current_user.build_post(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Your post was created!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:message)
  end
end
```

**app/view/posts/new.html.erb**

```
<% if policy(:post).create? %>
  <%= form_for(@post) do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_area :message %>
    <%= form.submit "Post" %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  You cannot post.
<% end %>
```

This code assumes the user is authenticated. If you haven't incorporated authentication, you'll need to use a gem for that, or roll your own implementation. I'd recommend [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance).

Good luck!